# Play framework redirecting to other method returns 303 in test

Tags: testing, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have 2 endpoints: `GET /users/me` and `GET /users/:id`. I want to redirect the first to the second, passing the current user's ID. So I've made this method:

```
def getCurrentUser = SecuredAction { implicit request =>

  request.identity.id.map { currentUserId =>
    logger.info(s"Returning current user $currentUserId's profile")
    Redirect(routes.UserController.getUserById(currentUserId))
  }.getOrElse(InternalServerError)
}
```

This works fine and I don't get a 303 (I think) with postman. However, the following test fails because the status is 303:

```
val result = userController.getCurrentUser()(authenticatedRequest)
status(result) mustBe OK
```

Is this some quirk of the testing framework? I thought the syntax I was using was for a silent internal redirect. I don't actually want to return a 303 to the client.

How can I test this and does the method I've written perform a silent internal redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result can never be OK (that is equivalent to a  http status 200) since the two status you're returning are 303 (Redirect) and 500 (InternalServerError).

Why don't you want to return a Redirect status?

If you want to return a OK status, you could replace this line:

```
Redirect(routes.UserController.getUserById(currentUserId))
```

by the method `getUserById`.

Comment: I don't want to return a 303 because I don't want an extra roundtrip. Also, the replacement you suggested doesn't work because `getUserById` is an async action controller as well, and I get an error `Expression of type Object doesn't conform to expected type Result`. I'm looking for a way of one controller method transparently forwarding to another controller method without returning a 303 in between. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: No it is not possible without using the rooting system ans so without returning a 303. What I wanted to tell you is to use directly the methods used by UserController.getUserById (If there is no methods used, extract one in a service and make it used by UserController.getUserById and by getCurrentUser).